# How do pyspark select and map differ in terms of output values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Why do these two methods of transforming this dataframe result in different output dataframes? Using select on the dataframe and map on the rdd seems to output the same values, but when I take the average of a column I get different results. What's going on here?

```
wrong_parsed_data_df = parsed_points_df.select((parsed_points_df.label - min_year).alias('label'), 'features')
parsed_data_df = parsed_points_df.rdd.map(lambda row: LabeledPoint(row['label'] - min_year, row['features'])).toDF()

# View the first point
print '\n{0}'.format(wrong_parsed_data_df.first())
print '\n{0}'.format(parsed_data_df.first())

print '\n{0}'.format(wrong_parsed_data_df.count())
print '\n{0}'.format(parsed_data_df.count())

print wrong_parsed_data_df.printSchema()
print parsed_points_df.printSchema()
```

Ouputs:

```
Row(label=79.0, features=DenseVector([0.8841, 0.6105, 0.6005, 0.4747, 0.2472, 0.3573, 0.3441, 0.3396, 0.6009, 0.4257, 0.6049, 0.4192]))

Row(features=DenseVector([0.8841, 0.6105, 0.6005, 0.4747, 0.2472, 0.3573, 0.3441, 0.3396, 0.6009, 0.4257, 0.6049, 0.4192]), label=79.0)

6724

6724

root
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

None
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
```

Then:

```
average_train_year = (parsed_train_data_df
                    .selectExpr('avg(label)').first())[0]

wrong_average_train_year = (wrong_parsed_train_data_df
                        .selectExpr('avg(label)').first())[0]

print average_train_year
print wrong_average_train_year
```

Outputs:

```
54.0403195838
54.0570419918
```

Comment: Can you show the types? How many records are there?

Comment: There are 6724 records and each is a tuple of label and features. The label is a float, and the features is a DenseVector of floats. You can view an example of the first row in the second block of code in my question.

Comment: Do you think there are some sort of floating point rounding errors going on here?

Comment: This is my guess and this is why I ask about types. Remember that DataFrame could store data as `float`,  `double` or `decimal` which won't map to directly to Python `float` and order of aggregations is non-deterministic. It is pretty large error but not impossible.

Comment: Thank you very much. My intuition is telling me that you're right, though I'm not exactly sure why. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: By any chance can you share the data and can perhaps dig into this a bit?  As well, could you provide the schema of the parsed_points_df?

Comment: I don't have direct access to the data, unfortunately, but what I'm working with is derived from UCI's million song dataset http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/. I'm working through an online tutorial available via databricks at this location: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5510861642806775/2291419291252851/7282726714117736/latest.html

Comment: I've added the schema of `parsed_points_df` into the second code block in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable solution is an error in your code - you are using `parsed_data_df` in first cell and `parsed_train_data_df` in the second one.

Comment: Whoops, thank you for pointing out that error. Unfortunately it was just an error I made transcribing my code into stack overflow, and not present in my source code, so something else is at play here. I've corrected the text in my question.

Comment: Just for your further information this is how those derivative dataframes were created: `parsed_train_data_df, parsed_val_data_df, parsed_test_data_df = parsed_data_df.randomSplit(weights, seed)
wrong_parsed_train_data_df, wrong_parsed_val_data_df, wrong_parsed_test_data_df = wrong_parsed_data_df.randomSplit(weights, seed)`